# Catastrophic backtracking occurred while matching inline base64 stream in Email body

Tags: regex

I am trying to match inline base64 stream inside HTML with below REGEX.
But it is throwing Catastrophic backtracking error.

**Regex**:`(?>src=\"data).*?(\">)`

**Sample data:**
`src="data/image:base64, iVakjsdlfjasldkfjaksjdaksjdflahdsklfjakdsljflkadsfjkjadshfkjahsdfkljahdsflkjadshflkjadshflkjasdhfklashdffasdf"==>`

*[The stream data is MANY lines]*

The REGEX works for few lines of Stream, but throws Catastrophic error for MANY lines of Stream.

Kindly share your thoughts.

Comment: If you need a regex here, you could use a mere `src="data([^"]*)"` and grab Group 1 value.

Comment: "*throws Catastrophic error*" - what's the error message, and which regex engine/implementation are you using?

Comment: thanks for the response, I need to match all the matching patterns, because I had to replace them with empty space.

Comment: I am using Java.
The error message - Catastrophic backtracking error.

Comment: Ok, `String result = text.replaceAll("src=\"data[^\"]*\"", "src=\"\"");`?

Comment: Regular expressions are usually not a good idea for html (or xml) and using a html parser might be a better idea.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks much..it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the problem is in the excessive backtracking caused by the lazy dot pattern applied on a long text. This is a common Java regex issue.

In most cases, you may solve it using a *character class* instead of a lazy dot.

Here, you may use `[^"]*` instead of `.*?`:

```
String result = text.replaceAll("src=\"data[^\"]*\"", "src=\"\"");
```

Here,

- `src="data` - matches `src="data`
- `[^"]*` - matches any 0 or more chars other than `"`
- `"` - a `"` double quotation mark.